# subtract m rows of dataframe from other m rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe with n rows. All values in dataframe can be assumed to be integers. I wish to subtract particular m rows from another set of m rows. For eg. i wish to do-

```
df[i:i+m] - df[j:j+m]
```

This should return a dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NumPy representation of your sliced dataframes and feed into `pd.DataFrame` constructor:

```
res = pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[i:i+m].values - df.iloc[j:j+m].values,
                   columns=df.columns)
```